# Why does \tl_if_in (and \clist_if_in) insert extra tokens with \mathrm

Tags: math-mode, expl3, token-lists

I encountered a strange behaviour I can’t explain. In my code for a highlighting macro I tried to use `\tl_if_in` to do a basic math class test. But when `\mathrm` is part of the tokens to be tested some extra tokes (i.e. what follows `\mathrm{…}`) are inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_const:Nn \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { +-=/ }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \highlight }{ m }{
   \tl_if_in:NnT \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { #1 } {
      % ...
   }
   #1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Inserts what comes after \verb|\mathrm{...}|
\[ \highlight{x} + \highlight{\mathrm{d}x} \]

works with additional group
\[ \highlight{x} + \highlight{{\mathrm{d}x}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is the same with `\clist_is_in`, except that there is also an additional comma in the output.

---

**note:** Actually my question is kind of xy problem, I came to this while working on a solution for capturing the math class: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369903/4918.

---

**update:** with `\tl_to_string` added the test is allay *true* …

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ \highlight }{ m }{
   \tl_if_in:NnT \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { \tl_to_string:n { #1 } } {
      T
   }
   #1
}
```

**update 2:** with most TL stringified I can’t make it work either …

```
\tl_const:Nn \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { \tl_to_string:n { +-=/ } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:NnT { NfT }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \highlight }{ m }{
   \tl_if_in:NfT \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { \tl_to_string:n { #1 } } {
      T
   }
   #1
}
```

Comment: could you please enlarge the attached image?

Comment: @Moriambar I’m already working on it ;-) trying to find out why it is that much scaled down while/after uploading …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's documented: the `<token list>` to search for cannot contain `{` or `}`.

[image]

Stringify both TL (constant and test) should do the trick, but you need two additional cs variants for this solution:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:NnT { NfT }

\tl_const:Nx \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { \tl_to_str:n { +-=/ } }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \highlight }{ m }{
   \tl_if_in:NfT \c_pirkl_math_rel_symbols_tl { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } {
      T
   }
   #1
}
```

Comment: Damn … how stupid I am. I read the sentence multiple times but didn’t noticed that the _replacement_ of `#1` contains braces … any ideas how to work around?

Comment: Actually my question is kind of xy problem, I came to this while working on a solution for capturing the math class: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369903/4918

Comment: Hm … when I add `\tl_to_string` (see OP edit) the test always is _true_

Comment: And how can I do this (see my try in the OP; update 2)

Comment: I saw that I used `string` instead of `str`. But I think you found a solution. I took the liberty to add it to your answer, hope this is ok?!

Comment: @Tobi OK for the edit, but the second variant is already provided.

Comment: Ah … I was confused by a `\tl_to_string undefined` error O:-) Thanks for your help!